# How to select the first element in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
$extensions = array(
    '.info'     => array('whois.afilias.net','NOT FOUND'),  
    '.com'      => array('whois.verisign-grs.com','No match for'),
    '.net'      => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
    '.co.uk'    => array('whois.nic.uk','No match'),        
    '.nl'       => array('whois.domain-registry.nl','is free'),
);
```

How do I echo the '.com' or '.co.uk' (not the array that is inside the '.com' or '.co.uk', but just the TLD) without a foreach loop. `echo $extensions['.com'];` doesn't work, because that gives back: Array

**EDIT:** I want to select on the key itself not on the array number. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print_r(array_keys($extensions));
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But I don't want to select on the array number. Since that can vary from time to time. Do you have antoher solution?

Comment: @GuidoVisser: The numbering cannot vary because `array_keys` controls it; `0` will always be the first key, `1` the second, etc.

Answer (score 4):

php 5.4
`echo array_keys($extensions)[0];`

php 5.3
`$keys = array_keys($extensions); echo $keys[0];`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to just for 1 output

```
$arrext = array_keys($extensions);
print_r($arrext[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To echo the key is only necessary if they are unknowned. If you know the key, like you described in your question with: "echo $extensions['.com'];" you are probably better of just trying: echo ".com";

BUT if you don't know them and want to output for example the first one you could do like this:

```
<?php
$extensions = array(
    '.info'     => array('whois.afilias.net','NOT FOUND'),
    '.com'      => array('whois.verisign-grs.com','No match for'),
    '.net'      => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
    '.co.uk'    => array('whois.nic.uk','No match'),
    '.nl'       => array('whois.domain-registry.nl','is free'),
);
$keys = array_keys($extensions);
echo $keys[0]; //will output ".info"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will grab all the keys for you. 
For example,

```
 
  $array = array_keys($extensions);
```

Then you can simply call

```
 
  print $array[0];    //displays .info
  echo $array[1];  // displays .com
  echo $array[2];  // displays .net
```

Comment: Yes, the array_keys functions return ONLY the **keys** of your original array as a 1-dimensional array. So, you can access the specific element using its index. No looping involved at all.

Comment: So, you want to be able to select by  $extensions["info"]; if you do that, it'll give you the ` array('whois.afilias.net','NOT FOUND')` ; I'm sure we'll be able to help better if we understand more what the requirement is; you also might consider unvoting all the answers, as they answered the question in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really wanted is `key($extensions)`, the problem is that you can't pick the array position with key(), so you have to either use a loop or assign all the keys into a new array like the other solutions.

The only ways to move the pointer is using `next()`, `prev()`, `reset()` or `end()`, which moves the pointer 1 position to the left/right on the array, or the array's first/last element

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, you can also 'shorthand' this to something like :

```
echo array_keys($extensions)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also the reset() function, which returns the first item in an array (and resets its internal pointer to the first element).

```php
$keys = array_keys($extensions);
$first = reset($keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [array_key_first](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-key-first.php) (PHP 7 >= 7.3.0, PHP 8).

```
$firstExtensionKey = array_key_first( $extensions );
$firstExtension = $extensions[ $firstExtensionKey ];
```